# Validation loss (mae) decreasing but validation metric (mae) not decreasing

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, lstm

**Issue that I am facing:** the training mae loss, training mae error (metric), validation mae loss are decreasing but the validation mae error fluctuates but it's overall trend is not decreasing.

**Model description**: consists of two networks(timedistributed CNN and timedistributed Dense layers respectively applied to each temporal slice of input in the sample) the output of which merge into one and then are fed to the first LSTM layer as a sequence in time. The output of this LSTM goes to the second LSTM layer which finally gives the output.

**Model loss and metric:**
tensorflow model loss in model.compile method = MAE
tensorflow model metric in model.compile method = MAE

**Model output:** forecast 6 numbers of the target label at a 10 minute interval (i.e. 6 numbers for the next one hour)

**Model input:** input data for one hour. Images to the CNN branch. Image timestamp specific tabular features to the Dense branch. The interval between the data points in both the images and their respective tabular features is 10 minutes.

Training size: 76,600 samples (from year 2018 to 2021)
Validation size: 13,500 samples (year 2022)

**Regularization used:** L2 and Dropout in CNN & dense branches and LSTM.

**Learning rate used**: 2e-4 which decays at a rate of 0.4 after every 5 epochs till 1e-5.

**Epochs:** 20

eg: input data from 9am to 9.50am will consist of 6 timestamps separated at 10 minute interval. At each of these timestamps we'll have an image and corresponding tabular data features. The output will be 6 numbers at 10am, 10.10am ,10.20am, 10.30am, 10.40am and 10.50am for the target label.

**What have I tried:** I have played around with learning rate and the number of layers in the model which helped me to decrease everything except for validation mae error. If I apply more regularization then: training mae loss, training mae error, validation mae loss don't decrease as much as with little regularization.

I am not able to understand as to what would it mean if everything except for validation mae is decreasing.

*Also, if it's important to know: the training mae loss is decreasing faster than the validation mae loss.*

Pasting the links to the relevant images (not allowed to paste inline images by stackoverflow).

[The graph of train vs validation metric(mae)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xd5RH.png)
[The graph of train vs validation loss(mae)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uN95.png)

Thank you for all the help in advance.

Comment: What is the difference between MAE error and loss?

Comment: @Plagon: loss is the loss argument in the tensorflow model.compile method. It is used by the model to optimize the model fit on the training data and evaluate the model performance on validation data. I have chosen MAE as the loss. By error, I meant the model.compile metric which is used to see how well the model performs on a given dataset. I have taken the metric as MAE as well. As I understand the metric is used for us to check how well the model is performing on training and more importantly validation data as the model learns. I'll edit my question to improve the clarity.